# After AJAX call change id value in order to stop jQuery selection to work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button which makes an `AJAX` call. I want this call to be executed once, so I thought that if I change the button's id the `$("#btn1").on("click", function() {` will not work anymore.

Despite the button's id has changed to `id="btn0"` the jQuery selection continues to work..

What am I missing?

```js
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '#',
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("After ajax call");
      $("#btn1").attr("id", "btn0");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn1">Click me</button>
```

Comment: You can disable the button instead of changing id. $('#btn1').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: Yes, I agree with that but I am most curious why the above solution isn't working...